# Java - many calls to Math.random() mess up loop

Tags: java, random

I have the following method:

```
public LinkedList<Object> init(int counter) {
    LinkedList<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();
    double decision, value, key;
    int max1 = 700;
    int max2 = 1000;

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        decision= Math.random();

        if (decision<= 0.2) {
            key = Math.random() * 1.5;
            value= Math.random() * max1 ;
            list.add(new A(value, key));
        } else {
            value= Math.random() * max2 ;
            list.add(new B(value));
        }
     }

     return list;
}
```

The problem I get is this: if I call this method using

```
init(100);
```

and then check the size of the resulting list, it is not always `100`. Instead, the number of elements in the list varies depending on the values i choose for `max1` and `max2`. If I choose `max2 = 1000000` for example, I end up with a list of about 15 elements. I suspect this has something to do with how `Math.random()` works, but have no idea how it happens. Is the problem about threading?

In case someone wants to try this, here are templates for classes `A` and `B` (the workings of which don't play into this):

```
public class A {
    public A(double value, double key) {}
} 

public class B {
    public B(double value) {}
}
```

Comment: The problem is not about threading. As far as you have let us know there is only one thread running in your program.

Comment: Do you see any exception anywhere? Do you have try-catch block in the code which calls this?

Comment: @Niklas: I suspected Math.random() might be running a thread in the background; I did not create any additional threads myself.

Comment: Your function is perfectly fine. Show us how you're calling it and determining the size of the list it has returned.

Comment: Even if Math.random() runs any number of threads in the background, it only makes sense for those to finish before returning a number to you. Your code will not proceed until random() has returned.

Comment: I've tested your code and I always get 100 objects in the list. Your making a mistake somewhere else, the code you posted is fine. For future reference Math.random() is just a plain old function that returns a value, it should never interfere with code outside itself.

Comment: Your function seems to be working fine. The problem seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: @TJ: No exceptions, no errors, everything but the number of elements in the list works as expected... and as I test my code again I realize I made a mistake and the list works fine.

Comment: I tested your code as well and consistently get 100 items in the list.

Comment: As far as I can see you should have `counter` objects in the list, from which aprox 20% should be `A` and the rest `B`. `list` is a local variable so it should be thread-safe. As @NPE said you should put here the calling code. The problem seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks all, instead of deleting the question, why don't all of you post a very short reply so I can upvote? You put time into this and helped me out, I'd like to give you credit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I suspected Math.random() might be running a thread in the background; I did not create any additional threads myself.

No, `Math.random()` does not run any threads in the background.

In fact, your function is perfectly fine. I've tested it extensively and it does exactly what one would expect. It always returns exactly `counter` elements.

I therefore have to conclude that your problem lies elsewhere, i.e. outside the code that you're showing us.